# Alert before applying filter in Ag-grid if data of grid is edited by inline editing

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am using Ag grid in my Project. I enabled inline edit in grid.
There is a problem which I am facing currently. I want to give an alert that there is some data which is edited, if user is going to change the set of filters  after doing some inline changes in the grid columns.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Answer (score 0):

listen to `onFilterModified` event while defining your `gridOptions` there you can do following

```
onFilterModified : function(){
    var celleditDefs = gridOptions.api.getEditingCells();
    if(celleditDefs.length){
        alert('there is some data which is edited');
           }   
     }
```